# Spark scala - Output number of rows after sql insert operation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have simple question, which I can't implement. Let's say I have following code:

```
...
val df = sparkSession.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE $DB_NAME.$TABLE_NAME PARTITION (partition) SELECT test, 1 as partition")
val rowCount = df.rdd.count()
printf(s"$rowCount rows has been inserted")
...
```

How to get the number of rows inserted by spark sql?

Comment: you can count the rows before insert and count after insert and subtract later with the first

Comment: That is clear, thanks for response. But I'm trying to think - how to do this using one operation and don't loose time for extra query execution.

Answer (score -1):

Before and after insert statement take the count of available rows and subtract it after insertion you will get the count if rows inserted.

Comment: this might give you wrong results, if in the meantime another parallel transaction completed.